# capture server matrix like CPU, Memory etc using Jmeter pefmon plugin

Tags: jmeter, perfmon

I am setting up perfmon plugin to capture server matrix while runnign load test from jmeter.

I have load balancer, separate Jmeter box and server whose matrix I want to capture. Where should I put my perfmon-agent? should it go to Jmeter box or server whose matrix is to be captured.

Comment: Server whose matrices to be collected

Answer (score 0):

It must go to the machine, you're going to monitor, sticking to your terms: `server whose matrix is to be captured`

Monitoring JMeter health is also vital as you need to ensure that JMeter has enough headroom to operate as if it lacks resources - it will not be able to send requests fast enough. However if you're sure that there are no problems with JMeter machine - put the [ServerAgent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md) to the server, you're going to monitor and set its hostname or IP address in the [PerfMon Metrics Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) listener

Also be aware that there is a way of monitor the server without installing any extra software, however the server needs to run [SSH server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers) (i.e. the majority of [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) systems have it enabled out of the box). Check out [How to Monitor Server Resource Utilization with JMeter’s SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener) for more details if interested.